# Magento : How to make customer Login in POPUP OR Drop down menu ?

Tags: login, popup

**Copy Files From customer**

\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\customer.xml

to

\app\design\frontend[THEME_PACKAGE]\default\layout\customer.xml

**then  in that xml find :**

`<customer_logged_out>` this section
then

make like this

```
 <customer_logged_out>
       <reference name="right">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
        
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
    </customer_logged_out>
```

**then copy the file**

app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form

copy form folder to our theme folder

app\design\frontend[THEME_PACKAGE]\default\template\customer\form

then

**FOR mini.login.phtml  USE THIS CODE LIKE THIS **

```
      <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post">
                   <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra')?>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <h2> <?php echo $this->__('LOGIN oder ANMELDEN') ?></h2>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Adresse</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="login[username]" id="mini-login" class="input-text form-control" /> 
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Passwort</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="login[password]" id="mini-password" class="input-text form-control" />
                                  </div>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-uppercase">anmelden</button>
                                  <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="#regis_2">Passwort vergessen?</a></p>
                                  <p><a href="#regis_1">Neuer Kunde? Jetzt registrieren!</a></p>
                                </form>
```

call in phtml via this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header_customer_form_mini_login') ?>
```